# Normalize large rasters with gdal.translate

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate

i have a series of ndvi images that i am trying to normalize with gdal to run some calculations, but i think i'm missing something.

per:
    https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/include/python/gdal_python.i

```
scaleParams --- list of scale parameters, each of the form [src_min,src_max] or [src_min,src_max,dst_min,dst_max]
```

my original  stats are

```
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=-0.194, Maximum=0.459, Mean=0.103, StdDev=0.073
```

i set my newmin and newmax to 0 and 1

then i

```
my_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(scaleParams = [[-0.194, 0.459,newmin, newmax]], format = 'GTiff',
                                      creationOptions = ['TFW=YES', 'COMPRESS=LZW']

gdal.Translate(gdaloutput, my_raster, options=my_options)
```

yet my output is

```
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=-30.148, Maximum=105.483, Mean=26.477, StdDev=18.837
```

I am getting the statistics with

```
srcband = gtif.GetRasterBand(1)

# Get raster statistics
stats = srcband.GetStatistics(True, True)
```

I had thought this was the correct way to get the statistics?
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#loop-through-all-raster-bands

i tried with a different raster and changed my min and max to floats, from 0 and 1 to 0.0 and 1.0. which gave me

```
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=0.226, Maximum=1.083
```

from the original of

```
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=-0.211, Maximum=0.439
```

I also read somewhere about avoid setting the new max higher or the new min lower than the original, so following that, setting new min to 0 and new max to 0.439, for the new raster

i got

```
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=0.099, Maximum=0.475
```

which places my new max higher than the existing.

What am i doing wrong?

Edit:

without the double brackets

Changing

```
[[src_min,src_max,dst_min,dst_max]] to [src_min,src_max,dst_min,dst_max]
```

you get

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

both

```
ComputeRasterMinMax()  and ComputeStatistics()
```

returns

```
(-0.19442784786224365, 0.4585714042186737)
```

Comment: I would first check that the reported min and max are correct and not a fast estimate that is computed from a sample of pixels.

Comment: It might be worth trying two other methods https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Band-class.html: ComputeRasterMinMax or ComputeBandStats.